# MAUI reference to webview control from Android MainActivity.cs file

Tags: android, webview, maui

I have a .NET MAUI app that I'm developing for Android and I have a WebView control in the MainPage.xaml file.

```
<WebView x:Name="webView" Source="somewebsite"/>
```

I want to handle the "back" key to navigate to the previous page if possible. I'm wondering how I can reference that WebView control from the MainActivity.cs file in the Android folder.

```
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    public override bool OnKeyDown(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (keyCode == Keycode.Back)
        {
            var webView = //WebView in MainPage.xaml

            if (webView.CanGoBack)
            {
                webView.GoBack();
                return true;
            }
        }

        return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
    }
}
```

Am I on the wrong track?

Edit:
Using the OnBackButtonPressed method in my MainPage.xaml.cs file doesn't navigate to the previous page. It just closes the app.

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        if (webView.CanGoBack == true)
        {
            webView.GoBack();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: `Page` already has a `OnBackButtonPressed` method

Comment: OnBackButtonPressed doesn't work for me some reason.

Comment: please [edit] your question to include the relevant code and explain exactly what you mean by "doesn't work"

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very descriptive. See my edited post above.

Comment: I just deployed the app to my phone and the back button worked as intended the first time I used the app. But after closing the app and opening it again, the back button closed the app instead of navigating to the previous page.

Comment: You can't reference a control from non-UI code. Use [Messenger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the following code to do that.

In the xaml:

```
<WebView x:Name="webview" Source=""/>
```

And in the page's `OnBackButtonPressed` method:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
#if ANDROID
        var web = webview.Handler.PlatformView as Android.Webkit.WebView;
        if (web.CanGoBack())
        {
           web.GoBack();
           return true;
        }
           
#endif
        return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
    }
```

Or you can also use the static variable to do that. But this will cause memory leak, becasue the MainPage will never be recycled untill the app be killed.

In the xaml:

```
<WebView x:Name="webview" Source=""/>
```

And in the page's code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
#if ANDROID
    public static WebView webView;
#endif
    public MainPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
#if ANDROID
        webView = webview;
#endif
    }
}
```

In the MainActivity:

```
public override bool OnKeyDown([GeneratedEnum] Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
    {
        if(keyCode == Keycode.Back)
        {
            var web = MainPage.webView.Handler.PlatformView as Android.Webkit.WebView;
            if (web.CanGoBack())
            {
                web.GoBack();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for showing how to do it in the Android MainActivity.cs file. I haven't had success with using the "OnBackButtonPressed" method. It works fine the first few times and then quits working until I clear the app storage.
The "OnKeyDown" method works fine.